# converting csv file into json format in python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, csv

I have written a code to convert my csvfile which is '|' delimited file to get specific json format.

Csv file format:

```
comment|address|city|country
crowded|others|others|US
pretty good|others|others|US ....
```

I have tried with other codes as well since I'm new to python I'm stuck in between. If somebody helps me to correct the mistake I'm doing it would be helpful.

```
import csv
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

csv_file = 'test.csv'
json_file = csv_file + '.json'


def main(input_file):
    csv_rows = []
    with open(input_file, 'r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        title = reader.fieldnames
        for row in reader:
            entry = OrderedDict()
            for field in title:
                entry[field] = row[field]
            csv_rows.append(entry)

    with open(json_file, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(csv_rows, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
        f.write('\n')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(csv_file)
```

I want in json format as below

```
{ 
 "reviewer": {
    "city": "",
    "country": ""   
    "address": "Orlando, Florida"
  },
```

But I'm getting output like this:

```
[
  {
    "COMMENT|\"ADDRESS\"|\"CITY\"|"COUNTRY":"Crowded"|"Others"|"Others"|
  },
  {
    "COMMENT|\"ADDRESS\"|\"CITY\"|"COUNTRY":"pretty good"|"Others"|"Others"|
  },
```

Comment: how to get the same output in nested json format? I'm getting in this format.[
    {
        "ADDRESS": "Others",
        "CITY": "Others", 
        "COUNTRY": "Others" } ] But I want the output in nested json format like { 
 "reviewer": {
    "city": "",
    "country": ""   
    "address": "Orlando, Florida"
  }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the separator parameter. Instead of:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
```

Use:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter='|')
```

Comment: Thanks. I got the json structure now.

Comment: How can I check for particular field value in the above program I have written. I have 2 fields 'recommendation' and 'rating'. Based on recommendation I need to set value for rating, like if recommendation is 1 then rating is 1 and vice versa

Comment: This is the link for other question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55333086/how-to-check-for-specific-field-values-based-on-some-condition-while-converting