# How to check for specific field values based on some condition while converting csv file to json format

Tags: json, python-2.7, csv

Below is the code to convert csv file to json format in python. 
I have two fields 'recommendation' and 'rating'. Based on the recommendation value I need to set the value for rating field like if recommendation is 1 then rating =1 and vice versa. With the answer I got I'm getting output for only one record entry instead of getting all the records. I think it's overriding. Do I need to create separate list for that and append each record entry to the list to get the output for all records.
 here's the updated code:

```
def main(input_file):
csv_rows = []
with open(input_file, 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter='|')
    title = reader.fieldnames
    for row in reader:
        entry = OrderedDict()
        for field in title:
            entry[field] = row[field]
        [c.update({'RATING': c['RECOMMENDATIONS']}) for c in reader]
        csv_rows.append(entry)

with open(json_file, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(csv_rows, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
    f.write('\n')
```

I want to create the nested format like the below:

```
"rating": {
"user_rating": {
  "rating": 1
},
"recommended": {
  "rating": 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you've read the file in, using the csv.DictReader, you'll have a list of dicts. Since you want to set the values now, it's a simple dict manipulation. There are several ways, of which one is:

```
[c.update({'rating': c['recommendation']}) for c in read_csvDictReader]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: with the above code I'm getting only one record values in the output instead of all records. Do I need to store the above code result into some variable and use it?

Comment: update modifies in place. I'd like to see what's in read_csvDictReader, if you don't mind